# WCF: How to find out if service is called?

Tags: wcf

I have a requirement where I should write WCF service that is called by another external service, which code is not under my control. I only know that my service is called by that external service in this way:

```
string content = client.getData("http://localhost:1111/Service.svc", param);
```

My service is located at the address that is actually first parameter in external service method, which means my service was called somewhere inside the body of external service method.

So, my question is - how can I be signaled inside my service that my service was called by that external service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can create two endpoint for different clients (real client and external servise)

2) you can write specific behavior and realize functionality by additional paramert which will be only into behaviors

Comment: 1) Excuse me, I didn't catch your point. Why do I need 2 endpoints?

Comment: 2) I don't understand it at all.

Comment: first endpoint for real clients and second for external service

Comment: In this case there's no other real clients because real client is external service.

Comment: wcf has behaviors, you can write code which will be run when wcf-message send and reciew, you can add paramert clienType and understant which strem from external service

Comment: I've just found that article. Thank you anyway.

Comment: One more question. I suppose I should write such inspection class on service side. Correct? If so, how can I use it on service side to catch the message from client?

Comment: you must write behaviors at both sides, but if you want to know about client's connection only, server-side behavior enough

Comment: Do you mean I should implement IDispatchMessageInspector interface only? The IClientMessageInspector interface is not needed to be implemented?